# PATCH request failing

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm unable to send a PATCH request through GuzzleHttp in Laravel that I'm otherwise able to make through the `curl` command-line utility. Here's how it looks in curl and works:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -d '{"custom_fields":[{"content": "23","id":"476"}]}' https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/rest/v1/contacts/1205764?access_token=qaj56sadew2ddduh968x4hdky
```

And here's what I tried:

```
$url = 'https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/rest/v1/contacts/' . $order->contact->id . '?access_token=' . $infs_token;

$response = $client->request('PATCH', $url, array(
    'json' => array(
        "custom_fields" => array(
            'content' => $infs_points,
            'id' => env('INFS_POINTS_FIELD_ID')
        )
    )
));
```

The response I get when using the code is `400 Unprocessable Entity`. I have verified that the URL and variables being used are correct. It looks like the problem is inside `custom_fields`, which needs to have an array containing an object containing the data (I don't have the object in my code, I think). Does anyone notice something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: just go to `request` method, and check what url made using dynamic parameters

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR The URL is fine, but I think the problem is the extra `{}` inside `custom_fields`. Notice how it contains an array which contains an object that contains the data. So far I have an array that contains the data. How do I add the object?